# ASP.NET Core: validation attributes are ignored on fields defined in children types

Tags: asp.net-core, model-validation

My ASP.NET Core 2.1 API exposes the following input DTO in a POST endpoint:

```cs
[Route("test")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("endpoint")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([Required]MyDTO dto)
    {
        // Some code
    }
}
```

```cs
public class MyDTO
{
  [JsonProperty("foo")]
  [Required]
  public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

The `Foo` class is defined as follow:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
public abstract class Foo
{
  [JsonProperty("foo_type")]
  [Required]
  public string FooType { get; set; }
}
```

The `FooConverter` class is able to instantiate the right implementation based on the `foo_type` field:

```cs
public class FooConverter : JsonConverter<Foo>
{
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override Foo ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Foo existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        Foo target = this.CreateFoo(jObject);
        serializer.Populate(jObject.CreateReader(), target);

        return target;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Foo value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private Foo CreateFoo(JObject jObject)
    {
        string fooType = jObject.Value<string>("foo_type");
        switch (fooType)
        {
            case "foo1":
                return new Foo1();
            case "foo2":
                return new Foo2();
            default:
                throw new JsonSerializationException($"Invalid 'foo_type' '{fooType}'");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is one of the implementations of the `Foo` abstract class:

```cs
public class Foo1 : Foo
{
  [JsonProperty("bar")]
  [Required]
  public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that the `[Required]` attribute on `Foo1.Bar` is ignored by ASP.NET validation, even though the `[Required]` attribute on `Foo.FooType` works as expected. How can I automatically validate the fields defined in the implementation types so that it works the same as with other fields?

Comment: where have you invoked the validation? a filter or have you manually called to validate the model in the controller?

Why do you not validate the Foo object on entry thus ensuring all values are valid and then map to a specific object based off the foo_type property? I would also have set the foo_type as an enum of specific values and ensure its one of those values.

Comment: In practice the foo type is an enum, I put string here for simplicity. The validation is the one performed automatically by ASP.NET Core MVC on API endpoints (I updated the question to clarify that).

Comment: The validator only knows about the abstract properties and not the derived class. Looking at it, I think you are trying to do too much. Simplify the validation on the dto only, and use fluent validation  / custom data annotations to validate certain properties when the FooType is x. This ensures the properties for each given type are valid. In the post method you can then use your JsonConverter manually.

Comment: on a side note, for property annotations plz use custom name resolved e.g. `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` this would simplify your validation a lot... also I would suggest to use `FluentValidator`, which handles lot of such stuff easily...

Comment: `FluentValidator` is a nice lib but it doesn't help at all for my use case. Native .NET Core validation attributes are perfectly fine for my app. Custom contract resolvers would allow me to reduce the code base by removing the `JsonProperty` attributes, but that's not related to the issue, and not something I want to do: explicit `JsonProperty` sometimes saved me from inadvertently introducing API breaking changes after a refactoring. But then again, that's an other debate.

Comment: asp.net core is using metadata generated by Declaring type to visit the children of the model. See [DefaultComplexObjectValidationStrategy](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3.0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Validation/DefaultComplexObjectValidationStrategy.cs#L33). `ModelMetadata` you see there is based on Declaring type not on Runtime type.

Answer (score -1):

**Replace:**

```
var jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
```

**with:**

```
JToken jObject = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything. At this point in the code, the `Foo` instance is not yet created, so the validation attributes are not available.

Comment: `Load` actually calls `ReadFrom`: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L2223